# How can I import typings from a similarly named file in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have two files:

Folder:
- my-file.d.ts (Has typings)
- my-file.ts (Has data objects that use the typings)

I'm trying to import the typings from my-file.d.ts as:

import { Typing } from './my-file.d.ts';

I keep getting a error warning from tslint saying:

> An import path cannot contain '.d.ts' extension. Consider using './my-file' instead.

I know this is a convinience for me but, in this case if I just use './my-file' only, it just points back to 'my-file.ts' which does not contain the typings I need.

How can I get it to point to the typings file properly in an Angular 5 cli-project?

Answer (score 0):

### Just remove  '.d.ts' from your path name in import statement. this may work

In this case you can take help from here 
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3169-adding-custom-typings-files-d-ts-in-an-angular-2-typescript-application.htm

Comment: As mentioned in my post if I use the './my-file' only (which has no '.d.ts') it points back to 'my-file.ts' which is where I already am.